# How Do I programmatically trigger or take control of model binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, model-binding

I have hundreds of forms, with `@model Dictionary<string,CustomType_i>` CustomType_i is form specific model!

instead of writing an action foreach form, I'm trying to submit them to a single controller action. Here is what I tried:

```
   public ActionResult ProcessForm(string formName, Dictionary<string,dynamic> mymodel){
  swich(formName){
    case "Customer":
    ///want to tell mvc to bind to Dictionary<string,Customer>
    break;
    case "Business":
    ///want to tell mvc to bind to Dictionary<string,Business>
    break;
  }
```

}

I have tried to convert `myModel` to `Dictionary<string,Customer>` using `.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value as Customer)` but it remains null, which perhaps means none key is of type Customer!
When I change `dynamic` into `Customer`, then it works for the case of Customer form, not other forms!

How can I trigger Model Binding to a specified Type?

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` binds your model before any code in your method is executed. Its too late, andbinding has already failed because it can't bind to `dynamic`. While you could write your own model binder, it will be far more code than having an `ActionResult` method for each view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own ModelBinder extending the IModelBinder interface or de DefaultModelBinder.

Basically you must override the `BindModel` method.

I think you should write something like this:

```
public class MyCustomBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                            ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpaces(request.Form.Get("formName")))
        {
            switch(formName){
                case "Customer":
                /// Instantiate via reflection a Dictionary<string,Customer>
                ...
                // Return the object
                break;
                case "Business":
                ///Instantiate via reflection a Dictionary<string,Business>
                ...
                // Return the object
                break;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
    }
}
```